# In Prestashop, how to get category of last product added?

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I don't have that much experience with Prestashop, php, and Smarty.
How do I get the category of lastProductAdded?
I am trying to make the "continue shopping" button redirect to the category of the last product added.

`<a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($lastProductAdded.category->id)|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="button_large" title="{l s='Continue shopping'}">&laquo; {l s='Continue shopping'}</a>`

The following code doesn't seem to work, giving category id of 0 for some reason. (I have no idea whether it makes sense either)
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

(The variable lastProductAdded and function getCategoryLink are already defined in-built)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Prestashop 1.4.x you need to modificate Cart::getLastProduct() with this code:

```
public function getLastProduct()
{
    $sql = '
        SELECT cp.`id_product`, cp.`id_product_attribute`, p.`id_category_default`
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_product` cp
        JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p ON (cp.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)
        WHERE `id_cart` = '.(int)($this->id).'
        ORDER BY cp.`date_add` DESC';
    $result = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sql);
    if ($result AND isset($result['id_product']) AND $result['id_product'])
        return $result;
    return false;
}
```

Regards

Comment: I saw this answer just as I was in the process of upgrading. Oh well. LOL. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `$lastProductAdded.id_category_default` instead of `$lastProductAdded.category->id`

Regards

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've tried your solution, but it returns http://example.com/caegory.php?id_category=0. The output is "There is 1 error : Missing category ID" (It should have returned id of 6)

Comment: I try it for Prestashop 1.5.2.0 and it works. <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($lastProductAdded.id_category_default)|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="button_large" title="{l s='Continue shopping'}">&laquo; {l s='Continue shopping'}</a>. What version do you use?

Comment: Oh really?? I use Prestashop 1.4.9.0. That's weird. :(

Comment: It's about time I upgraded to 1.5. Thank you sir!